# Change colour of SVG element before modal box opens and keep it that colour while the box is open

Tags: javascript, svg, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to change the colour of the SVG element I click on to open a modal box. This seems more difficult than it would otherwise be, possibly because of the hover behaviour I have going on with the SVG element already.

Atm the element is red and scaled larger when the cursor is on it, but goes back to white when I click on it to open a modal. How do I keep it red when the modal is open and only change back to white when the modal closes? I still want the hover behaviour I have already when I don't click anything.

asylumQ is a Q shape and AsylumTr is a hole in the middle. When the mouse hovers over the Q or the hole in the Q the Q shape turns red (this isn't perfect, but using js to group the 2 elements together did not work and grouping them in the SVG also wrecked the behaviour so maybe I will fix this later).

Here is the js:

```
            asylumQ.hover(function() {
            asylumQ.attr({ opacity: 1, fill: 'red', stroke: 'red' });
            asylumQ.animate({ transform: 's2,2'}, 300, mina.easein);
            asylumTr.animate({ transform: 's2,2'}, 300, mina.easein);          
        },
            function() {
                asylumQ.attr({ opacity: 1, fill: 'white', stroke: 'white' });
                asylumQ.animate({ transform: 's0.8,0.8'}, 300);
                asylumTr.animate({ transform: 's0.8,0.8'}, 300, function () {
                    asylumQ.animate({ transform: 's1,1'}, 20);
                    asylumTr.animate({ transform: 's1,1'}, 20);
                });
            }
        );

        asylumTr.hover(function() {
            asylumQ.attr({ opacity: 1, fill: 'red', stroke: 'red' });
            asylumQ.animate({ transform: 's2,2'}, 300, mina.easein);
            asylumTr.animate({ transform: 's2,2'}, 300, mina.easein);
        },
            function() {
                asylumQ.attr({ opacity: 1, fill: 'white', stroke: 'white' });
                asylumQ.animate({ transform: 's0.8,0.8'}, 300);
                asylumTr.animate({ transform: 's0.8,0.8'}, 300, function () {
                    asylumQ.animate({ transform: 's1,1'}, 20);
                    asylumTr.animate({ transform: 's1,1'}, 20);
                });
            }
        );

        asylumTr.click(function() {
            asylumQ.attr({ opacity: 1, fill: 'red', stroke: 'red' });
            $('#asylumModal').modal('show');
        });
```

Comment: Define a CSS class with the colour you want and then add it to the element class list while the dialog is open.  And remove it again when you close the dialog.

Comment: Hmm - not working for me cld you show me the code? - I want to change the colour of an element that isn't in the modal. I'm trying to change the svg element I clicked on to open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Define a CSS class with the colour you want and then add it to the element class list while the dialog is open. And remove it again when you close the dialog.

Example:

```js
$("#myrect").click(function() {

  // Add a class to the rect which keeps it with the hover styling.
  // Note: We can't use jQuery's addClass() for this because it doesn't work with SVGs
  $("#myrect").attr("class", "dialogIsOpen");
  
  // Open the modal
  $("#myModal").modal();

  // Attach a handler for the dialog's hide event so we can remove the class we added
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#myrect").removeAttr("class");
  });

});
```

```css
rect {
  transform: scale(1,1);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

rect:hover,
.dialogIsOpen {
  transform: scale(1.25,1.25);
  fill: red;
}

/* position the modal out of the way so we can see the SVG */
.modal-dialog {
  margin-top: 160px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<svg>
  <g transform="translate(150 75)">
    <rect id="myrect" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
  </g>
</svg>


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>An example modal</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine except for the scaling - I'm using an svg I made in Illustrator so inserting the translation into the group tag doesn't work for me without major modifications which are too complicated - I would just have to start again. Combining the transforms in css doesn't work either :( Any suggestions for controlling the scaling in Chrome?

Comment: How I have done the SVG in this example is immaterial.  All you should be looking at is how I am opening the modal and how I am adding and removing the class.